# How to make Dark Mode in a Flutter with Tabbar

Tags: flutter, tabbar, darkmode

I'm new in stackoverflow and in Flutter. Anyway I will give a try to ask here for help.

I want to implement Dark/Light Mode in a Flutter Application by a press of a Button which is inside of the App Bar. The switching between Dark ans Light with the button it is already working. The problem is that I have a Tab Bar and when I press the button it turns Dark only around the Tab Bar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvE7X.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlf59.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'my_app.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/mainscreen.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Test'),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'station_0.dart';
import 'station_1.dart';
import 'station_2.dart';
import 'station_3.dart';
import 'station_4.dart';
import 'station_5.dart';
import 'station_6.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isDark = true;

  final ThemeData _light = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.green,
  );
  final ThemeData _dark = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      darkTheme: _dark,
      theme: _light,
      themeMode: _isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            CupertinoSwitch(
              value: _isDark,
              onChanged: (v) {
                setState(() {
                  _isDark = !_isDark;
                });
              },
            )
          ],
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[600],
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          elevation: 4,
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 900,
            height: 700,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: const Alignment(0, 0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: DefaultTabController(
                  length: 7,
                  initialIndex: 0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: const [
                       TabBar(
                        labelColor: Colors.black,
                        indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Main',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  ))),
                          Tab(
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Station 1',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  ))),
                          Tab(
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Station 2',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  ))),
                          Tab(
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Station 3',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  ))),
                          Tab(
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Station 4',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  ))),
                          Tab(
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Station 5',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  ))),
                          Tab(
                              child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Station 6',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                                  ))),
                        ],
                      ),
                       Expanded(
                        child:  TabBarView(
                          children: [
                            MyFrontPage(),
                            MyStation1(),
                            MyStation2(),
                            MyStation3(),
                            MyStation4(),
                            MyStation5(),
                            MyStation6(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:toggle_switch/toggle_switch.dart';

class MyFrontPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFrontPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyFrontPage> createState() => _MyFrontPageState();
}

class _MyFrontPageState extends State<MyFrontPage> {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: ListView(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30), children: <Widget>[
            Wrap(spacing: 100, children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'All Stations',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                    ),
                  )),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: ToggleSwitch(
                  minHeight: 40.0,
                  minWidth: 60.0,
                  cornerRadius: 20.0,
                  activeBgColors: [
                    [Colors.red[800]!],
                    [Colors.green[800]!]
                  ],
                  activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                  inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                  initialLabelIndex: 1,
                  totalSwitches: 2,
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  labels: [' OFF', 'ON'],
                  radiusStyle: true,
                  onToggle: (index) {
                    //print('switched to: $index');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),

            //Space between-----------------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 100,
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                ]),

            //Station 1 Auswahl--------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 50, children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Station 1',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                    ),
                  )),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: ToggleSwitch(
                  minHeight: 30.0,
                  minWidth: 50.0,
                  cornerRadius: 20.0,
                  activeBgColors: [
                    [Colors.red[800]!],
                    [Colors.green[800]!]
                  ],
                  activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                  inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                  initialLabelIndex: 1,
                  totalSwitches: 2,
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  labels: [' OFF', 'ON'],
                  radiusStyle: true,
                  onToggle: (index) {
                    //print('switched to: $index');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),

            //Space between-----------------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 100,
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                ]),

            //Station 2 Auswahl--------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 50, children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Station 2',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                    ),
                  )),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: ToggleSwitch(
                  minHeight: 30.0,
                  minWidth: 50.0,
                  cornerRadius: 20.0,
                  activeBgColors: [
                    [Colors.red[800]!],
                    [Colors.green[800]!]
                  ],
                  activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                  inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                  initialLabelIndex: 1,
                  totalSwitches: 2,
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  labels: [' OFF', 'ON'],
                  radiusStyle: true,
                  onToggle: (index) {
                    //print('switched to: $index');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),

            //Space between-----------------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 100,
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                ]),

            //Station 3 Auswahl--------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 50, children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Station 3',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                    ),
                  )),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: ToggleSwitch(
                  minHeight: 30.0,
                  minWidth: 50.0,
                  cornerRadius: 20.0,
                  activeBgColors: [
                    [Colors.red[800]!],
                    [Colors.green[800]!]
                  ],
                  activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                  inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                  initialLabelIndex: 1,
                  totalSwitches: 2,
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  labels: [' OFF', 'ON'],
                  radiusStyle: true,
                  onToggle: (index) {
                    //print('switched to: $index');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),

            //Space between-----------------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 100,
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                ]),

            //Station 4 Auswahl--------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 50, children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Station 4',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                    ),
                  )),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: ToggleSwitch(
                  minHeight: 30.0,
                  minWidth: 50.0,
                  cornerRadius: 20.0,
                  activeBgColors: [
                    [Colors.red[800]!],
                    [Colors.green[800]!]
                  ],
                  activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                  inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                  initialLabelIndex: 1,
                  totalSwitches: 2,
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  labels: [' OFF', 'ON'],
                  radiusStyle: true,
                  onToggle: (index) {
                    //print('switched to: $index');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),

            //Space between-----------------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 100,
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                ]),

            //Station 5 Auswahl--------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 50, children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Station 5',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                    ),
                  )),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: ToggleSwitch(
                  minHeight: 30.0,
                  minWidth: 50.0,
                  cornerRadius: 20.0,
                  activeBgColors: [
                    [Colors.red[800]!],
                    [Colors.green[800]!]
                  ],
                  activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                  inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                  initialLabelIndex: 1,
                  totalSwitches: 2,
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  labels: [' OFF', 'ON'],
                  radiusStyle: true,
                  onToggle: (index) {
                    //print('switched to: $index');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),

            //Space between-----------------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 100,
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: <Widget>[
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                ]),

            //Station 6 Auswahl--------------------------------------------------
            Wrap(spacing: 50, children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 5.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Station 6',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
                    ),
                  )),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                child: ToggleSwitch(
                  minHeight: 30.0,
                  minWidth: 50.0,
                  cornerRadius: 20.0,
                  activeBgColors: [
                    [Colors.red[800]!],
                    [Colors.green[800]!]
                  ],
                  activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                  inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                  inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                  initialLabelIndex: 1,
                  totalSwitches: 2,
                  // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                  labels: [' OFF', 'ON'],
                  radiusStyle: true,
                  onToggle: (index) {
                    //print('switched to: $index');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ]),
        ));
  }


}
```

Comment: You can wrap the TabBar in a Material widget and set the color attribute

Comment: Why do you have two `MaterialApp` instances? Try using only one in `MyApp`.

Comment: Thanks Xoltawn and Nick101 for your help. Using only one MaterialApp instance gave me the result that i wanted. Thanks again for your help.